# SceneKit Debug Options

Tags: ios, collision-detection, scenekit

All,

There is a specific switch to make normals, geometries and other parts of all nodes in a scene visible.
I thought I kept it somewhere in my code, but I must have erased it somehow.
I need this function because the contact detection doesn‘t seem to work right.
I want to detect if thrown grenades in a tunnel touch the tunnel walls. Right now, most of them just fall through.
Anybody know the command?

Answer (score 1):

Like showBoundingBoxes?

SCNDebugOptions

Edit:
You can put it UIViewController along with...

```
gameScene.allowsCameraControl = false
gameScene.showsStatistics = false
```

Go to this link and see SCNDebugOption for a complete list.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523281-debugoptions

Comment: I think that was it. Thank you so much. You don‘t happen to have a full command line at hand, would you?

Comment: Is there a way to turn the options off, after having turned them on? I want to establish a switch function in a kind of editor: just turn the visibility of the physicsShapes on (and off) if necessary.